# Apply function to array where one of function's factors is dependent on row index of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time

For one of my projects I need to apply a function to an array in the following way:

```
a = value_function(arr, beta=beta_adj(beta, T = i), alpha = alpha/i)
```

where value_function is the function that needs to be applied to the array arr to create the goal array a.

The beta is an input of the value_function and is determined by another function called beta_adj, which takes two values as input (beta and T).

```
beta_adj(beta, T = i)
```

The T-factor should be equal to the row number of the array arr (i is there to indicate that).

The same should be done for the alpha factor, where alpha will be divided by the row number (i again is there to indicate the row number).

```
alpha = alpha / i
```

Is there a way to improve time efficiency and avoid using a for loop to iterate through each of the array rows (see example implemented below)?

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i == 0:
        a = value_function(arr[0], beta=beta_adj(beta, T = i), alpha = alpha/i )
    else:
        a = np.concatenate((a, np.matrix(value_function(arr[i], beta=beta_adj(beta, T = i), alpha = alpha/i)))), axis = 0)
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be nicer if you post all of your functions (or mimicking) as well.

Comment: Everything is depending on structure of  `value_function`. Probably,  you can replace the loop with vectorized numpy notations. This could significantly increase speed of computation. Another way is rewrite computationally expensive parts of your code using Cython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `for` loop, currently, the first iteration creates `a`, and the subsequent iterations concatenates a `matrix` to `a`. Each such concatenation is an expensive operation, and repeated concatenation is definitely a bad idea.

**Do not create or concatenate to `a` inside the `for` loop.**

**Option 1:**

In the `for` loop, just keep accumulating a `list` of references to `matrix` objects returned by `value_function`. After exiting the `for` loop, make just `one call` to `numpy.concatenate()`, passing the list of matrix objects as the first argument.

**Option 2:**

If the exact sizes (number of elements) of the returned matrix objects is known beforehand (before the `for` loop), use those numbers to create the `a` array beforehand (before the `for` loop), **in its full size**, but without any initialization. To do this, you can use `numpy.empty()`.

Then, inside the `for` loop, use each matrix object to perform assignments to relevant portions of this full-size `a` array. Again, we are avoiding repeated concatenation, so that will definitely speed up things.